# ASP.NET Mvc 4 Save Uploaded File With a Diffrenet Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

The problem is what the title says. I manage to upload an image, resize it and save the resied image to a specific folder with a different name than the name of the uploaded image.

I use this code ...

```
WebImage img = new WebImage(this.File.InputStream);
img.Resize(width, height).Crop(1, 1);
img.Save(dir, extenstion, true);
```

And it works. But when I try to save the file with `HttpPostedFileBase::SaveAs(dir)` method with a new filename, it saves a blank image with 0 bytes. When i try to save it as the same filename that was uploaded, it saves correctly. But, as one will think, user can save images with the same filename, so that behaviour is not desirable.

So, the question is, how to save a uploaded image with `SaveAs()` but with a new filename that i generate?

I tried these links

[Upload tut 1](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/)

[Upload tut 2](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files)

and I save searched extensivly but I couldn't find anything that would solve this.

I also tried saving the original uploaded image with `WebImage` class after I save the resized one but it also saves it blank.

EDIT

Code for saving the original uploaded image...

```
string dir = "~/Content/images/large/";
string newFilename = "2154689.jpg" // filename is generated and then added the correct extension
UploadedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(dir, newFilename));
```

This works but it saves the image with the filename uploaded by the user

```
UploadedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(this.File.FileName)));
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in Asp.net and C# for about 15 days and this was a mistake on my part. You have to make the filename the sam extension as the file uploaded. So this works...

```
File.SaveAs(Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(newFilename + "." + ext)));
```

A pretty silly mistake on my part.